# Broadcast Data with Android

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, wifi-direct, broadcasting

I'm looking to develop an application that necessitates multiple devices sending and receiving messages. These messages need not be acknowledged (necessarily), they just need to be sent to all potential recipients in the area. Further complicating the issue, I can't have a centralized solution (i.e. one where a fixed server relays data between clients).

I've looked into a bunch of technologies that should support this to no avail. BLE has a 'broadcast mode' that should do the trick but as of Android 4.4.3 they have yet to support this feature. Wi-Fi direct requires two peers to establish a connection. Same goes for 'classic' Bluetooth.

Is there any technology that is supported by Android that communicates in this way? I'm running into a lot of trouble trying to create a solution that could function without this technology and I cannot.

Comment: Does it suffice to just reach the devices in the same wireless network?

Comment: Can you restrict the devices you want to use.  What is the range you need?  How much data? How often?

Comment: Range would preferably be around 30ft, smaller is okay. Devices can be limited to Android phones, if I need to be more specific for a proof of concept thats fine. Data would be negligible for each packet (between 4 and 16 bytes). Data transmission would be irregular.

Comment: @Hans Kratz what exactly do you mean by wireless network? If you have an idea that would allow me to communicate nearby Android phones, please share.

Comment: If you can restrict yourself to a limited number of Android phones then you could look to use ANT see http://www.thisisant.com/

Comment: You can use UDP broadcast/multicast to reach other devices in the same wireless network. This will not work for devices connected via cellular data.

Comment: I see what you mean. UDP needs a centralized participant (i.e. an access point), so I cannot use that. Thanks for the input.

Comment: For UDP broadcast/multicast the devices just need to be connected to the same (wireless) network. There is no need for a centralized server component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is bit of a moot point now that Android L will support BLE in all modes. However, for those who are looking for an alternative they can use immediately, ANT+ (as @Ifor suggested in his comment) is a viable alternative.